# Partial Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I perform a postback on just a portion of my page?

Answer (score 3):

Your question needs A LOT more explanation of the problem but, from what i can tell, you should take a look at using [Update Panels](http://www.codegod.de/webappcodegod/updatepanel-tutorial-aspnet-ajax-AID281.aspx).  It will allow you to update only certain parts of the page and give you the AJAX-y feeling.

Again, this is just a guess so more information would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

      a portion of your page

    </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

for postback some part of page you can use updatepanel

for more details [Vist this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

hey , u can use AJAX update panel.
Drag and drop the Ajax Update Panel control onto ur page.
and put the controls that u want to update inside that panel.

Also dont forget to put Script Manager Control.

For more informations check ASP.net Ajax Control Toolkit Examples 
[asp.net/ajax](http://www.asp.net/ajax). The concept is too simple .